# Python tkinter treeview get full path

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, path, treeview

How do i get the full path of a selected node in a treeview?

I use:

```
    curItem = tree.focus()
    item_list = tree.item(curItem)
```

But this only gives me the node i selected not the name of the "master" node.

I use the Treeview do Display the data in a Folder.

- Folder_1

  - File.txt

I want "Folder_1\File.txt" as a result."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
item_iid = tree.selection()[0]
parent_iid = tree.parent(item_iid)
node = tree.item(parent_iid)['text']
```